# Python SQL Query - unknown column

Tags: python, mysql, sql

Information: inserting a statistic, that is a temperature value. The info should be "temp" so that I know that the log is about the temperature

I'm trying to execute next query from a python script

```
info = "temp"
sql = 'insert into stat_bus (addr, grp, info, status) 
VALUES (' + address + ', ' + group + ', ' + info + ', ' + status + ')'
```

I get following error: Unknown column temp in field list
The address, group and status don't give erros.

***I have tried other possibilities for the string parsing (I guess that's the error?) but can't get it working. Thanks in advance***

Comment: What are you using for the database connection? All the libraries that implement the [Python Database API](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/) should do the escaping for you. You shouldn't construct the query on your own.

Comment: consider using prepared statements http://zetcode.com/db/mysqlpython/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that with your query, SQL isn't interpreting `temp` as a the *string* "temp", but as a *variable* named `temp`.

If you print `sql`, you will get the following query:

```
insert into stat_bus (addr, grp, info, status) VALUES (something, something, temp, something)
```

Whereas you would want this query:

```
insert into stat_bus (addr, grp, info, status) VALUES ("something", "something", "temp", "something")
```

(Note the quotes around `temp`)

Just change your Python code by adding the quotes in the right places:

```
info = "temp"
sql = 'insert into stat_bus (addr, grp, info, status) 
VALUES ("' + address + '", "' + group + '", "' + info + '", "' + status + '")'
```